# Numeric UpDown control using dependency properties

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, callback, dependency-properties

So I'm at a loss to understand this.  I have a custom control that uses up/down buttons to increase/decrease the time as displayed on toggle buttons.  I have the `Content` property of the Toggles displaying the correct values of the `Hour` and `Minute` properties, and I'm now trying to set up the code-behind to increase the values.  According to the VS2010 debugger, it *is* increasing the value of the Hour property, but it's not changing the content of the Toggles to reflect this.  I have the binding mode set to `TwoWay`, and I'm using {Binding `RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Hour, Mode=TwoWay}` to bind to the value as this is within the `generic.xaml` file of the custom control.  Any ideas on how to make the displayed value update correctly?

**XAML:**  (Style templates removed to save space)

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:TimePicker}">
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Height}" />
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Width}" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="Transparent"
                        BorderThickness="1">
                    <StackPanel  x:Name="PART_Root"
                                 Orientation="Horizontal"
                                 HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                 VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}">
                        <!--Region Hour Button-->
                        <ToggleButton x:Name="PART_Hour"
                                      VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}"
                                      Margin="0"
                                      BorderBrush="Transparent"
                                      BorderThickness="0"
                                      Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Hour, Mode=TwoWay, BindsDirectlyToSource=True}">                                
                        </ToggleButton>
                        <!--EndRegion-->
                        <Label HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}"
                               VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}"
                               FontSize="14"
                               Content=":"/>
                        <!--Region Minute Button-->
                        <ToggleButton x:Name="PART_Minute"
                                      VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}"
                                      Margin="0"
                                      BorderBrush="Transparent"
                                      Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Minute}">                                
                        </ToggleButton>
                        <!--EndRegion-->
                        <StackPanel x:Name="PART_IncDecPanel"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                    Orientation="Vertical">
                            <Grid Height="{Binding ElementName=PART_Hour, Path=ActualHeight}">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Viewbox Stretch="Fill" Grid.Row="0">
                                    <!--Region Increase Button-->
                                    <Button x:Name="PART_IncreaseTime"
                                            HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}"
                                            VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}"
                                            BorderBrush="Transparent"
                                            BorderThickness="0"
                                            FontFamily="Marlett"
                                            Foreground="DimGray"
                                            Content="5"
                                            Padding="0"
                                            Click="PART_IncreaseTime_Click">                                            
                                    </Button>
                                    <!--EndRegion-->
                                </Viewbox >
                                <Viewbox Stretch="Fill" Grid.Row="1">
                                    <!--Region Decrease Button-->
                                    <Button x:Name="PART_DecreaseTime"
                                            HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}"
                                            VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}"
                                            BorderBrush="Transparent"
                                            BorderThickness="0"
                                            FontFamily="Marlett"
                                            Foreground="DimGray"
                                            Content="6"
                                            Padding="0">                                            
                                    </Button>
                                    <!--EndRegion-->
                                </Viewbox>
                            </Grid>

                        </StackPanel>

                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

**Code:**

```
public class TimePicker : Control
{
    #region Dependency Property Declarations
    public static DependencyProperty HourProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Hour", typeof(int), typeof(TimePicker),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata((int)12, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnHourChanged)));

    public static DependencyProperty MinuteProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Minute", typeof(string), typeof(TimePicker),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata((string)"00", new PropertyChangedCallback(OnMinuteChanged)));        

    #endregion

    #region Properties
    public int Hour
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(HourProperty); }
        set { SetValue(HourProperty, value); }
    }

    public string Minute
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(MinuteProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MinuteProperty, value); }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Events
    private static void OnHourChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        TimePicker time = new TimePicker();
        time.Hour = (int)e.NewValue;
        MessageBox.Show("Hour changed");
    }

    private static void OnMinuteChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
    #endregion

    static TimePicker()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(TimePicker), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(TimePicker)));
    }
}

public partial class TimePickerEvents : ResourceDictionary
{
    TimePicker time = new TimePicker();

    void PART_IncreaseTime_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        time.Hour += 1;

    }
}
```

Comment: why are you creating a `new TimerPicker` in `OnHourChanged`?

Comment: It was the only way I could access `Hour` instead of `HourProperty`.

Comment: `TimePicker timePicker = (TimePicker)sender;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you are using a Togglebutton to display the hour/minutes, I would think a Label/TextBlock would be better suited for that.

Change the binding of your ToggleButtons to

```
Content="{TemplateBinding Hour}"
```

Then in the code, override `OnApplyTemplate` as such

```
public override void OnApplyTemplate()
{
    var upButton = GetTemplateChild("PART_IncreaseTime") as Button;
    upButton.Click += IncreaseClick;

    var downButton = GetTemplateChild("PART_DecreaseTime") as Button;
    downButton.Click += DecreaseClick;
}

private void IncreaseClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Here would be a place to see what toggle button is checked 
    // (or which TextBlock last had focus) and increase Hour/Minute
    // based on that info
    Hour += 1;
}

private void DecreaseClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Here would be a place to see what toggle button is checked 
    // (or which TextBlock last had focus) and decreaseHour/Minute
    // based on that info
    Hour -= 1;
}
```

This should get you started. 
FYI: Within your OnHourChanged and OnMinuteChanged the sender is your control (TimePicker). So you can cast the sender to TimePicker and access all of your properties. Even your private properties.

Comment: The logic behind using a ToggleButton is that it comes with the built-in ability to stay selected, whereas Label does not.  As for TextBlock, I don't really want a cursor blinking on it, I just want it to be selected.  I'm sure I could override the cursor, but this just seemed more natural.  I am strongly considering switching to a RadioButton as base instead, but I wanted to get it working first.  :) I did try what you suggested, and it worked after changing `GetTemplatePart` to `GetTemplateChild`.  Thanks!

Comment: Woops, sorry about that Typo. I changed to the correct method name. I can assure you that clients would want to manually change time as well as an up/down. This is why a TextBox would be best. You can then use your Tab key to tab through your control and use your Up/Down buttons or use the scroll wheel or up/down keyboard keys. Start thinking about these now.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the WPF toolkit's numerical up down control?
http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=NumericUpDown

All you have to do is bind it to your properties two way.

Comment: Mostly because this was a chance for me to learn Custom Controls, but also because I'm really not a fan of reusing other content.  I'll draw ideas from other sources, but I like the challenge and learning opportunity that doing it myself provides.